# DHQMR DKNE1 D2QN6 DOX7V part identification

Tags: transistors, identification

[image: D2QN6]

[image: DHQMR]

[image: DKNE1]

[image: DOX7V]

[image: 7D]

I have several boards with these 4 parts used interchangeably. I can't find part numbers for any of them. Any help would be great.

I'm assuming some type of transistor. The labels on the board where these parts are used start with 'T'.

The transistors might be used as part of several subcircuits each taking a separate PWM and clipping it to be trapezoidal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply can't be an operational amplifier, since here are only 3 pins and opamp needs at least 5. It's a MOSFET (check data sheet on irlml6244 for example, page 8) , since infineon ones have markings like XYWLC where X is designator, Y-year, W-week (of production), LC - lot code. If you can provide more part of pcb maybe it will be more clear and I answer more clear. Also if you have multimiter, you can try to find parasitic diode between drain and source.

Comment: Thanks.  I need to do some more R&D to be able to provide you with partial or full schematic.  I will let you know.

Comment: Yeah all parts start with D so could be Infineon or International Rectifier IRLML5103.  Although it doesn't say anything about a line above or below lot code.  Also I don't understand when the middle character has both lines (above and below).

Comment: Lines showing features like noPb or so (also showed on page 8 of that data sheet). Lines depends on manufacturer also, so additional pcb pictures will be appreciated. I strongly believe that it is a MOSFET and it utilizes switching function, to ensure type and Vgs need more photos and apply voltage if possible

Comment: The 6-pin 7Du/7Dn is most likely onsemi MUN5214DW1T1G https://www.newark.com/on-semiconductor/mun5214dw1t1g/trans-50v-10-47kohm-sot-363/dp/80Y9477